# AngularJS controller: what is the right syntax?

Tags: angularjs, controller

I usually declare one controller this way:

```
.controller('myController', function($scope,/*other dependecies go here*/){
    // controller definition
};
```

However in some examples (including one from AngularJS's official documentation) I found something like:

```
angular.module('controllerExample', [])
  .controller('SettingsController2', ['$scope', SettingsController2]);

function SettingsController2($scope) {
     // controller definition
};
```

or simply (which is equivalent, I guess):

```
angular.module('controllerExample', [])
  .controller('SettingsController2', ['$scope', function(){
     // controller definition
   }
]);
```

Now, I don't understand what is the actual **difference** between **snippet 1)** and **snippets 2) and 3)**

Also, I don't understand why sometimes the same dependency is both outside the function definition and in function parameters (like snippet 3) ) but **outside** is **without $** and **inside** is **with** (sorry I can't find an example now. But I'm sure I had this situation).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

The array syntax is to prevent angular from breaking when the code goes through a minifier.  If you are not minifying your javascript, there really isn't a big difference other than you get to type more/less.  Angular reads in these functions as a string and processes them. Some minifiers screw that up, so that weird syntax is the current solution.

Comment: `$` just means that it's Angular built in service. Inside/outside doesn't affect the use of `$`

Answer (score 2):

@jwimmer's answer is correct but I want to offer one more possibility. You can clean up the syntax a bit and keep your code minification safe using `$inject`.

```
someCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'someDependency'];
function someCtrl($scope, someDependency) {
    ...
}

angular.module('someApp')
    .controller('someCtrl', someCtrl);
```

Comment: Not quite. My example uses `$inject`. It accomplishes the same thing though, just with a cleaner syntax in my opinion. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector

Comment: Also, by doing it this way you are keeping the string association of the injectables right with the definition, so if you were to add/remove a dependency then you will see and therefore remember to change the string reference